# add string to file after a specific line

Tags: php, string, file

I would like to know is there is a way to add string to a file after a specific line 
in php?
I have tried

```
file_put_contents
```

but it puts the string at the end of the file.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: use `file()`, should be in array format, from there use the keys

Answer (score 8):

Has been a long time but will be useful to anyone who come across this in future...

```
$f = fopen("path/to/file", "r+");

$oldstr = file_get_contents("path/to/file");
$str_to_insert = "Write the string to insert here";
$specificLine = "Specify the line here";


// read lines with fgets() until you have reached the right one
//insert the line and than write in the file.


while (($buffer = fgets($f)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($buffer, $specificLine) !== false) {
        $pos = ftell($f); 
        $newstr = substr_replace($oldstr, $str_to_insert, $pos, 0);
        file_put_contents("path/to/file", $newstr);
        break;
    }
}
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach, kinda verbose, but makes all modifications inline:

```
$f = fopen("test.txt", "tr+");

// read lines with fgets() until you have reached the right one

$pos = ftell($f);                   // save current position
$trailer = stream_get_contents($f); // read trailing data
fseek($f, $pos);                    // go back
ftruncate($f, $pos);                // truncate the file at current position
fputs($f, "my strings\n");          // add line
fwrite($f, $trailer);               // restore trailing data
```

If the file is particularly big, you would need an intermediate file.

Answer (score 0):

Also one way is to use `file()` function. In returns an array of the contents of that particular file per line. From there, you can manipulate the array and append that value on that specific line. Consider this example:

```
// Sample file content (original)
// line 1
// line 2
// line 3
// line 4
// line 5
// line 6


$replacement = "Hello World";
$specific_line = 3; // sample value squeeze it on this line
$contents = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if($specific_line > sizeof($contents)) {
    $specific_line = sizeof($contents) + 1;
}
array_splice($contents, $specific_line-1, 0, array($replacement)); // arrays start at zero index
$contents = implode("\n", $contents);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $contents);

// Sample output
// line 1
// line 2
// Hello World
// line 3
// line 4
// line 5
// line 6
```

Answer (score -1):

The following is my code

```
 function doit($search,$file,$insert)
{
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
$max=count($array);
for($a=0;$a<$max;$a++)
{if($array[$a]==$search) {
$array = array_slice($array, 0, $a+1, true) +
array($insert) +
array_slice($array, $a+1);
 break;}}
 $myfile = fopen($file, "w");
 $max=count($array);
 var str='';
 for($a=0;$a<$max;$a++)
 {str.=$array[$a].'\n';}
 fclose($myfile);
 }
```

You have to give the filepath (`$file`), the new line text (`$insert`) and the text of  the line(`$search`) after which the new line is to be inserted

Comment: It would be better to use `file()` instead of `explode(..., file_get_contents(...))`